# How to limit the result data in flexible seach query

Tags: database, limit, sap-commerce-cloud

I want to limit the result data in flexible search query.

Let's say query should return only 10 records each time (like LIMIT)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already answered your query, you can use LIMIT cause same as we use in MySQL.

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM {Product} LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {Product}
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT * FROM {Product} WHERE rownum <= 10
```

---

Though API

```
final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT * FROM {Product}");

query.setCount(10);
```

---

### Find more detail in [helphybris](https://www.helphybris.com/2015/02/flexible-search-limit-the-result-rows.html)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reply!

Comment: Do you know why it's not working when I try to use impex export tool?
ex. `"#% impex.exportItems(""SELECT * FROM {Product} "", Collections.EMPTY_MAP, Collections.singletonList( Item.class ), true, true, -1, -1  );"`
I have this error:
`Flexiblesearch error: SQL search error : You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '100 * FROM products item_t0 WHERE (item_t0.TypePkString IN  (8796100919378,87961' at line 1 query = 'SELECT TOP 100 * FROM products item_t0 WHERE (item_t0.TypePkString I`

Answer (score 4):

Use the `query.setCount(int)` method of the API.