# How to limit the number of results by flexible search in hybris

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, flexible-search

I want to limit the number of result using JobSearchRestriction. I want to limit not by a condition, but by "hard coded" number. Somethig like "LIMIT 10".

Is it possible to do that in hybris using JobSearchRestriction?

Comment: use query.setCount(int) --> make variable configurable either in any model or in properties

Comment: look here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133420/how-to-limit-the-result-data-in-flexible-seach-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to limit the result data in flexible seach query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51133420/how-to-limit-the-result-data-in-flexible-seach-query)

Comment: No, LIMIT 10 doesn't work on hana db, which I am using. And since it's a search restriction, it probably is appending on where query like and : "AND %searchRestrictionValue%", so I would not be able to use "AND LIMIT 10". 

Also, I don't have access to query.setCount because as I said, it's a search restriction, I only have controll over the value inside the query for search restriction.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM {Product} LIMIT 10
```

or

```
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM {Product}
```

For Oracle

```
SELECT * FROM {Product} WHERE rownum <= 10
```

Though API

```
final FlexibleSearchQuery query = new FlexibleSearchQuery("SELECT * FROM {Product}");

query.setCount(10);
```